# Swift tabbed app using same UIViewController multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need a way to add instances of the same UIViewController (from my storyboard) multiple times to the tabbarcontroller

Not sure what the best approach would be

Comment: could you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: basically the app will load in multiple instances of the same page, and the user will be able to add/remove pages and modify their settings (label text tc)

Comment: Does this article help: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-exploring-tab-bar-controller--cms-25470

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon in that article, he is creatign each page individually and adding them all (ctrl-drag tabbarcontroller to viewcontroller) but i want to be able to attach them to the tabbarcontroller in code, and have multiple instances of the same UIViewController as seperate tabs, and the amount of them i'm creating is not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create different instance on same view controller and add to tabbar controller .

```
let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“storyboard_id”) as yourViewcontroller
vc.tabBarItem = UItabbarItem(Title:“title” image:image tag:yourtag);

let vc1 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“storyboard_id”) as yourViewcontroller
vc1.tabBarItem = UItabbarItem(Title:“title1” image:image1 tag:yourtag);

tabbarController.setViewControllers([vc,vc1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```
let array = tabBarControllerName.viewControllers
```

This returns an array of all the ViewController within your tabBarController, so if your first ViewController is of class, let's say TestViewController we could do something like

```
let controller = array[0] as? TestViewController
```

Hope it will help you